# border-image-width in css

Tags: html, css

This is how MDN explains [border-image-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-width).

> The border-image-width CSS property defines the width of the border
>   image by defining inward offsets from the border edges. If the
>   border-image-width is greater than the border-width, then the border
>   image extends beyond the padding (and/or content) edge.

What it does not tell is what will happen if border-image-width is less than border-width ?

I did an example on it. Ran it on chrome 56. Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Border Image</title>
    <style>
        p.checkBorderImageWidth{
            border: 40px solid black;
            width:500px;
            border-image-source: url("1.png");
            /* Note that now border-image-slice defaults to 100% */
            border-image-width: 10px;
            outline: 1px solid black;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="checkBorderImageWidth">Hi this is just a demo</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Border image used is :

[image]

Result is:

[image]

So, as you see the solid black border is hidden though it is 40px and boder-image-width is 10px. Can anyone explain it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The border image is used instead of the 'normal' border:

source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

> The `border-image` property allows you to specify an image to be used *instead* of the normal border around an element.

Your citation explains that the border image will cover the padding and eventually content of the container if `border-image-width > border-width`.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Border Image</title>
    <style>
        p.checkBorderImageWidth{
            border: 40px solid black;
            width:500px;
            border-image-source: url("1.png");
            /* Note that now border-image-slice defaults to 100% */
            border-image-width: 10px;
            outline: 1px solid black;
        }

        p.checkBorderImageWidth2{
            border: 100px solid black;
            width:500px;
            border-image-source: url("1.png");
            /* Note that now border-image-slice defaults to 100% */
            border-image-width: 30px;
            padding: 5px;
            outline: 1px solid black;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="checkBorderImageWidth">Hi this is just a demo</p>
    <p class="checkBorderImageWidth2">The border covers the text.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Here the border covers the text:
[image: border covering text]